# How to get a list of the types of stopwords removed from dataset using QUANTEDA, R

Tags: r, quanteda

I'm working on a text dataset with `quanteda` in R. I've created a corpus from the dataset, then I created a dfm with all the punctuations and stopwords in English removed using the following:

```
dfm_nostp <- dfm(data, remove_punct = TRUE, remove=c(stopwords("english")))
```

Is there a way which I can inspect how many types of punctuations and stopwords I removed from the dataset in `quanteda`?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 1.5.2

summarize_texts_extended <- function(x, stop_words = stopwords("en")) {
  toks <- tokens(x) %>%
    tokens_tolower()

  # total tokens
  ndocs <- ndoc(x)
  ntoksall <- ntoken(toks)
  ntoks <- sum(ntoksall)

  # punctuation
  toks <- tokens(toks, remove_punct = TRUE, remove_symbols = FALSE)
  npunct <- ntoks - sum(ntoken(toks))

  # symbols and emoji
  toks <- tokens(toks, remove_symbols = TRUE)
  nsym <- ntoks - npunct - sum(ntoken(toks))

  # numbers
  toks <- tokens(toks, remove_numbers = TRUE)
  nnumbers <- ntoks - npunct - nsym - sum(ntoken(toks))

  # words
  nwords <- ntoks - npunct - nsym - nnumbers

  # stopwords
  dfmat <- dfm(toks)
  nfeats <- nfeat(dfmat)
  dfmat <- dfm_remove(dfmat, stop_words)
  nstopwords <- nfeats - nfeat(dfmat)

  list(
    total_tokens = ntoks,
    total_punctuation = npunct,
    total_symbols = nsym,
    total_numbers = nnumbers,
    total_words = nwords,
    total_stopwords = nstopwords
  )
}
```

It returns, as a list, the quantities you want:

```r
summarize_texts_extended(data_corpus_inaugural)
## $total_tokens
## [1] 149138
## 
## $total_punctuation
## [1] 13852
## 
## $total_symbols
## [1] 4
## 
## $total_numbers
## [1] 85
## 
## $total_words
## [1] 135197
## 
## $total_stopwords
## [1] 136
```